# Get first and last record for each date and calculate their difference

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to calculate the `DATEDIFF` in seconds between the First record for each date with `EventCode = 1` and the last record for each date with `EventCode = 2`.

I have posted a sample data set for 2 days here: http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/515591/calculate-the-difference-between-first-event-and-last-event-for-each-date

So this is how I am getting the First Record for each Date:

```
Select
    LogDate,
    StartOfDay = MIN(LogDateTime),
    EventCode
FROM (
        Select 
            LogId,
            LogDateTime,
            LogDate = FORMAT(LogDateTime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
            DriverId,
            EventCode
        FROM 
            #MyLogs
        WHERE EventCode = 1
     ) A 
Group By
        LogDate,  EventCode
```

And this is how I am getting the Last Record for each date where `EventCode = 2`

```
Select
    LogDate,
    EndOfDay = MAX(LogDateTime),
    EventCode
FROM (
        Select 
            LogId,
            LogDateTime,
            LogDate = FORMAT(LogDateTime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
            DriverId,
            EventCode
        FROM 
            #MyLogs
        WHERE EventCode = 2
     ) A 
Group By
        LogDate, EventCode
```

But how do I get the same in single result set? And I need to get the difference in seconds between the First Record for each date and Last Record for each Date.

Example of Result Set:

```
| Date        | StartOfDay              | EndOfDay                | Start - End |
|-------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|-------------|
| 20-Jul-2016 | 2016-07-20 04:00:32.000 | 2016-07-20 13:05:19.000 |             |
| 21-Jul-2016 | 2016-07-21 04:55:52.000 | 2016-07-21 14:49:25.000 |             |
|             |                         |                         |             |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Lennart's answer can be simplified to a single Group By:

```
SELECT LogDate, StartOfDay, EndOfDay, 
    DATEDIFF(s, StartOfDay, EndOfDay) AS ElapsedSeconds
FROM
  (
    SELECT
        -- instead of FORMAT better use a Standard SQL CAST:
        CAST(LogDateTime AS DATE) AS LogDate,

        MIN(CASE WHEN EventCode = 1 THEN LogDateTime END) AS StartOfDay,
        MAX(CASE WHEN EventCode = 2 THEN LogDateTime END) AS EndOfDay
    FROM #MyLogs
    WHERE EventCode in (1,2)
    GROUP BY
        CAST(LogDateTime AS DATE)
        -- Pivot in a single stepby removing EventCode 
  ) AS dt;
```

[see query](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/515905/calculate-the-difference-between-first-event-and-last-event-for-each-date)

Comment: You don't even need to use a subquery: `DATEDIFF(s, MIN(CASE WHEN EventCode = 1 THEN LogDateTime END), MAX(CASE WHEN EventCode = 2 THEN LogDateTime END),`

Comment: @JimmyB: Of course, but when the *start* and *end* need to be included, too, the MIN/Max must be repeated. Now it's a bit more readable and as long as there'n no Group By the optimizer should remove it anyway and you will get the same plan for both variations.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your query to:

```
SELECT LogDate, MAX(StartOfDay), MAX(EndOfDay), DATEDIFF(s, MAX(StartOfDay), MAX(EndOfDay))
FROM (
    Select
        LogDate,
        StartOfDay = MIN(case when EventCode = 1 THEN LogDateTime END),
        EndOfDay = MAX(case when EventCode = 2 THEN LogDateTime END),
        EventCode
    FROM (
        Select 
            LogId,
            LogDateTime,
            LogDate = FORMAT(LogDateTime, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'),
            DriverId,
            EventCode
        FROM 
            #MyLogs
        WHERE EventCode in (1,2)
     ) A 
    Group By
        LogDate,  EventCode
       ) B 
GROUP BY LogDate;
```

i.e. get both EventCode 1 and 2 from the derived table A, and use a case expression in the aggregate function. Then we need another nesting to get rid of null's from the case expression.

You might want to have a look at window functions, they can simplify this type of query a lot.

I have added my query to:

http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/515887/calculate-the-difference-between-first-event-and-last-event-for-each-date

Comment: Hi, The first query shows the Start and End in separate rows - Is there a way to show them in a single row? Like the example I added to the question - Note: You can test the Query on the data.stackexhange link I posted

Comment: See update in answer. +1 for adding sample data.

Comment: Thanks - Will the window function be more efficient performance wise than this?

Comment: Window functions are usually more efficient, but one have to test from case to case. Nevertheless it is a good technique to know, so if you haven't tried them I recommend doing so. If you get stuck post back and I or someone else can have a look.